# How to get greenbone NVTS data -GSF

Tags: string

I can get GCF by installing GVM and find it in my local file var/lib/gvm/plugins, but I have searced for GSF using lots of ways. I could not get it and just downloaded one file each in https://secinfo.greenbone.net/nvt, which is obviously stupid! Can anyone help me

just get GCF by installing GVM(openVAS) on Linux

Comment: you should add more context to your question. Add the full name of the abbreviations.To get more attention you could add tags for the used language and library. Some people ony watch their tags. Pleas provide a little reproducable sample to evaluate your problems easier.